# Creating a Slideshow in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery and l want to create a slideshow of images. I downloaded the latest version of jquery.
Here is my html code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>

   <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jq.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stl.css">


   </head>
   <body>

   <div id = "slideshow">

    <img src="images/chale-wote.jpg">
    <img src="images/accranight2.jpg">
    <img src="images/accra1.jpg">
    <img src="images/holidayinn.jpg">
    <img src="images/elmina.jpg">


    </div>


   </body>
   </html>
```

Here is my JQUERY code,l saved it as jq.js

```
      $("#slideshow > div").hide();    

      setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
       },  5000);
```

When l run it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There is no `('#slideshow > div')` could it be that you meant to wrap your images with divs?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code you have `img` inside `#slideshow`. But in your jq you try to hide and show `div` inside `#slideshow`. Which do not exist.

Change your code to below

```js
$("#slideshow img").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > img:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">

  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x250">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x150">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x100">
</div>
```